# Add translations that should not be cached from Controller

Tags: symfony, caching, symfony-2.8

In my app, I have two sorts of translations:

- **Static wordings** that are part of the template layout (like "Previous","Cancel"...)
- **Dynamic wordings** that are extracted from database and can change for every request (like a blog article title that can vary in database)

I use the Symfony translator service to use static wording in my twig templates, with the **trans** filter. It works fine with static wordings, but with dynamic wordings things are getting difficult.

I add my **dynamic** wordings like that, inside a controller action:

```
    $trans = $this->get( 'translator' );

    $trans->addLoader('array', new ArrayLoader());
    $trans->addResource('array', array('BLOG_ARTICLE_TITLE'=>$article->getTitle('french')), 'fr', 'messages');

    // ...

    return new Response();
```

And then, I use it with trans on my templates or with BazingaJsTranslationBundle in my frontend app.

I guess I have an issue with the cache : for dynamic wordings, I often get the old wording or the translation key on the page - even when the adding is done on the controller before returning the Response.

But when I clear the cache (app/console clear:cache) and reload the page, I get the right wordings.

Is there a way to tell Symfony to not cache dynamically added wordings ? 
Or another translator method that suits more the dynamic addition of translations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony Documentation:

> Translating Database Content
>
> The translation of database content should be handled by Doctrine through [the Translatable Extension](http://atlantic18.github.io/DoctrineExtensions/doc/translatable.html) or the Translatable Behavior
>   (PHP 5.4+). For more information, see the documentation for these
>   libraries.

Which is used like this:

```
use Gedmo\Translatable\Translatable;

// [...]
class Article implements Translatable
{
    /** @ODM\Id */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @ODM\String
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @ODM\String
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Locale
     * Used locale to override Translation listener`s locale
     * this is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property
     */
    private $locale;
```

**For your specific problem:**

You can remove cache file manually
Lexik translation bundle use this system. [see their Translator.php class below](https://github.com/lexik/LexikTranslationBundle/blob/master/Translation/Translator.php)

```
public function removeLocalesCacheFiles(array $locales)
{
    foreach ($locales as $locale) {
        $this->removeCacheFile($locale);
    }
    // also remove database.resources.php cache file
    $file = sprintf('%s/database.resources.php', $this->options['cache_dir']);
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        $this->invalidateSystemCacheForFile($file);
        unlink($file);
    }
    $metadata = $file.'.meta';
    if (file_exists($metadata)) {
        $this->invalidateSystemCacheForFile($metadata);
        unlink($metadata);
    }
}
/**
 * @param string $path
 *
 * @throws \RuntimeException
 */
protected function invalidateSystemCacheForFile($path)
{
    if (ini_get('apc.enabled')) {
        if (apc_exists($path) && !apc_delete_file($path)) {
            throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Failed to clear APC Cache for file %s', $path));
        }
    } elseif ('cli' === php_sapi_name() ? ini_get('opcache.enable_cli') : ini_get('opcache.enable')) {
        if (!opcache_invalidate($path, true)) {
            throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Failed to clear OPCache for file %s', $path));
        }
    }
}
```